# drop menu as menu control asp.net

Tags: asp.net, controls, drop-down-menu, aspmenu-control

i have a simple menu control here is the code

```
<asp:menu id="mainMenu" runat="server" orientation="Horizontal" maximumdynamicdisplaylevels="0" skiplinktext="    " staticdisplaylevels="2" cssclass="menua" staticselectedstyle-forecolor="DarkBlue" staticselectedstyle-font-underline="true" onmenuitemclick="mainMenu_MenuItemClick">
 <Items>
     <asp:MenuItem Text="Management" Value="mTabManagement"  NavigateUrl="TabManagement.aspx">
         <asp:MenuItem  Text="Auditing" Value="mAuditing" NavigateUrl=""></asp:MenuItem>
         <asp:MenuItem Text="Billing" Value="mBilling" NavigateUrl=""></asp:MenuItem>
         <asp:MenuItem Text="Reporting/Services" Value="mServices" NavigateUrl=""></asp:MenuItem>
     </asp:MenuItem>
     <asp:MenuItem Text="Payment Plan)" Value="mPayment" NavigateUrl="PaymentPlan.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
     <asp:MenuItem Text="Advocate" Value="mTabAdvocate" NavigateUrl="TabAdvocate.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
     <asp:MenuItem Text="Pay" Value="mPay" NavigateUrl="HowItWorks.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
     <asp:MenuItem Text="Parking Ticket Protection" Value="mProtection" NavigateUrl="Security.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>   
 </Items>         
 </asp:menu>
```

how can i make

```
 <asp:MenuItem Text="Management" Value="mTabManagement"/>
```

work like dropdownlist

Comment: You can't. It's expecting a collection of menu items - DDL is not a menu item.

Comment: Are you asking how to make it expand?

Comment: can you suggest anything besides javascript and jquery

Comment: yea i wanna know how to display like dropdown